# Where is the Father’s kingdom’s final location?

Tags: matthew, prophecy, heaven, kingdom-of-god

Jesus says

“I tell you I will not drink again of this fruit of the vine until that day when I drink it new with you in my **Father’s kingdom**.””
‭‭Matthew‬ ‭26:29‬ ‭

Where will this kingdom be situated geographically speaking? In the heavens or on earth? New or old?

Answer (score 2):

***Where will this kingdom be situated geographically speaking? In the heavens or on earth? New or old?***

Geography has to do with places on earth. Cosmology has to do with places in the universe. God's sovereignty is over everything in heaven and on earth. Our Sovereign is King of all Creation, and his kingdom rule is over all Creation.

When it comes to pass, as Jesus exhorted us to pray, "Our Father in heaven, hallowed be thy name, thy kingdom come, thy will be done in heaven as it is in earth..." then all Creation will be in that kingdom, with God as their sovereign.

Right now, before that glorious, all-encompassing rule of God reaches its ultimate fulfillment, we see aspects of that kingdom on earth. Those who are already subjects of God's kingdom already bow their knee to their sovereign, and they see the stark contrast between those who seek to extend that kingdom rule through obedience and proclamation of it, and everyone else, who do not. As stated in 1 John 5:19, "And we know we are of God, and the whole world lieth in wickedness."

Therefore, when God exerts his sovereign rights over all his Creation, destroying all wickedness, then the kingdom of God will once more be established in the new heaven and the new earth that must replace the corrupted heavenly and earthly systems - invisible to all but God's people, who have been given the Revelation of Jesus Christ to know the signs that expose the invisible wickedness in heavenly places currently pulling the strings of all those not prepared to bend their knee before God's throne.

Where the book of the Revelation deals with the four living creatures standing before the throne of God in heaven, that is to symbolise all aspects of God's material creation. By the time the Day of Resurrection and Judgment ends, they will no longer be seen in heaven, for all corrupt creation will have been destroyed by fire, replaced with "a new heaven and a new earth, in which righteousness will dwell" (2 Peter 3:10-14). ***Then the kingdom of God will reign supreme everywhere, be that visible or invisible, and every creature shall willingly bow their knee before God's heavenly throne.***

Comment: Up-voted +1. New heavens and a new earth.

Answer (score 1):

Matthew‬ ‭26:

> 29 I tell you I will not drink again of this fruit of the vine until **that day** when I drink it new with you in my **Father’s kingdom**.

There is a parallel account of the last supper in Luke 22:

> 14When the hour came, Jesus and his apostles reclined at the table. 15And he said to them, “I have eagerly desired to eat this Passover with you before I suffer. 16For I tell you, I will not eat it again until it finds **fulfillment in the kingdom of God**.”
>
> 17After taking the cup, he gave thanks and said, “Take this and divide it among you. 18For I tell you I will not drink again from the fruit of the vine until the **kingdom of God comes**.”

Matthew's Father’s kingdom is the same as Luke's kingdom of God, just different terminologies. Both refer to the future.

Moreover,
Matthew‬ ‭26:29 speaks of a particular day.
This day may allude to the celebrative day 4 chapters earlier in Matthew 22:

Matthew 22:

> 1 Jesus spoke to them again in parables, saying: 2“The **kingdom of heaven** is like a king who prepared a **wedding banquet** for his son.

> 30 At the resurrection people will neither marry nor be given in marriage; they will be like the angels in heaven.

This marriage is not between a man and a woman but between Christ and believers after the resurrection.

Where is the Father’s kingdom’s final location?

The final location will be on the new future earth after the resurrection.

Comment: Even though you answered the question and you have a lot of verses, it isn’t obvious how you connect them. Still i upvoted earlier

Comment: Thanks. I added more details :)

Answer (score 1):

This is an eschatological question. Therefore this interpretation I outline may not be universally accepted, so exercise caution.

This kingdom is on earth. We know this through the many Kingdom parables Jesus taught. But first Jesus has to ‘*win back*’ this Kingdom.

That’s what his second coming is for. We see this here…

**1 COR 15:24** *Then comes the end, when he delivers the kingdom to God the Father after destroying every rule and every authority and power.*

That’s why Israel is [still] so crucial to Gods plans. When they repent, and accept him as Messiah, he will return, fight on their behalf, defeat evil, and reign over this kingdom from Jerusalem. (Revelation 20). Then, after the Millennium period, he will deliver the Kingdom to his Father.

**REV 21:2** *And I saw the holy city, new Jerusalem, coming* ***down out of heaven*** *from God, prepared as a bride adorned for her husband;*

Coming down *out* of Heaven - **(on)to** the (new) earth, and inhabited by the saints.

Comment: I navigated through your post and stuck just to the points relevant to the question so as not to derail. I think you had a good explanation for your answer.

Comment: The New Jerusalem came down _on to a newly created earth_ and it was under _newly created heavens_.

Comment: @NigelJ ? I didn’t say it wasn’t? (a new earth). I just said the location was *on* earth.

Comment: @Dave One needs to specify which earth. It's important

Comment: @NigelJ - Done.

Answer (score 1):

**Where is the Father’s kingdom’s final location?**

the Father’s kingdom’s final location? **God's throne is in the heavens. Why?**

John 18:33-37 NET

Pilate Questions Jesus

> 33 So Pilate went back into the governor’s residence,[a] summoned
> Jesus, and asked him, “Are you the king of the Jews?”[b] 34 Jesus
> replied,[c] “Are you saying this on your own initiative,[d] or have
> others told you about me?” 35 Pilate answered, “I am not a Jew, am
> I?[e] Your own people[f] and your chief priests handed you over[g] to
> me. What have you done?”

36 Jesus replied, **“My kingdom[h] is not from this world.** If my kingdom were from this world, my servants would be fighting to keep me from being[i] handed over[j] to the Jewish authorities.[k] But as it is,[l] my kingdom is not from here.” 37 Then Pilate said,[m] “So you are a king!” Jesus replied, “You say that I am a king. For this reason, I was born, and for this reason, I came into the world—to testify to the truth. Everyone who belongs to the truth listens to[n] my voice.”

From Jesus' reply to Pilate, [Vs 36] “My kingdom is not from this world",  hence God's Kingdom is in the heavens, and not the earth. God's Kingdom will also have authority over the earth, Jesus  said,

Matthew 28:18 NASB

18 And Jesus came up and spoke to them, saying, “All authority in heaven and on earth has been given to Me.

Psalm 103:19 ASV

> 19 Jehovah hath established **his throne in the heavens;**  And his
> kingdom ruleth over all.

Isaiah 66:1 NASB

**Heaven Is God’s Throne**

> 1 This is what the Lord says:  “Heaven is My throne and the earth is
> the footstool for My feet. Where then is a house you could build for
> Me?  And where is a place that [a]I may rest?

Comment: I don’t dispute that God’s kingdom is currently in Heaven, which is what you answered and seem to extrapolate, therefore that it will be in Heaven permanently and forever this way. Is that what you’re saying because my question is specifically about the FINAL location.  I’m going to upvote it because some of your verses have been useful in ways that I didn’t expect.

Comment: Nihil Sine Deo:   Jesus who is King of God's kingdom , after his death ascended to heaven (Acts 2:33) hence, God's God's Kingdom is in Heaven.  That is the reason the Bible calls it a "heavenly kingdom". (2 timothy 4:18) . God's Kingdom although in heaven will rule over the earth, "“The kingdom of the world has become the kingdom of our Lord and of His [a]Christ, and He will reign forever and ever.”(Rev.11:15) Also Daniel 2:44

Comment: “Then the iron, the clay, the bronze, the silver, and the gold, all together were broken in pieces, and became like the chaff of the summer threshing floors; and the wind carried them away, so that not a trace of them could be found. But the stone that struck the image became a great mountain **and filled the whole earth**.”
‭‭Daniel‬ ‭2:35‬ ‭

That’s not in the heavens is it?

Comment: Nihil Sine Deo:  Jesus said:  "All authority in heaven and on the earth has been given to me.” (Matthew. 28:18) This authority was given to Jesus by God,  and as King of God's Messianic Kingdom, will do just that. He will obviously do this from heaven, remember Sodom and Gomorrah and the proud Pharaoh of Egypt, and Nebuchadnezzar  Daniel 4: 25, 34-35, God exercises his will on Earth and in Heaven.

Comment: That’s not how the prophecy reads, is it though? The gold is a kingdom, et cetera and now the stone filled all the earth, it established itself as a kingdom, area of influence. Let me ask you this, is it possible it’s both in Heaven and on earth or only in Heaven as you seem to insist?

Comment: Who is Gods kingdom for?

Comment: Nihil Sine Deo: Jesus as King of God's Kingdom (1 Tim. 6:15), after his resurrection ascended to heaven(Acts 2:33) Therefore God's Kingdom is in heaven. Although in heaven,this Kingdom will rule over the earth. Rev. 11:15 states“The kingdom of the world has become the kingdom of our Lord and of His [a]Christ, and He will reign forever and ever.” Also read  Daniel 7:13-14, 2 Peter 1:11, Luke 22:28-29

Answer (score 0):

Wherever God is, it’s spiritual, looking at it from a human perspective is false. Heaven is with God not a place, it’s relationship, kingdom is relationship

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I voted your answer up as it is correct, but it would be better if you would add the scripture to support it.

Answer (score 0):

When we read "new heavens and new earth", we must remember that evil is banished. There is no more war or deception or hurt anymore. God's kingdom is cosmic - it is everywhere.

> then comes the end, when he delivers up the kingdom to the God and Father, when he has abolished all rule and all authority and power. 1Cor 15:24

All life is now 'not' physical requiring food or air etc, all humanity that has accepted God's plan of salvation through Jesus has been given immortal life as Jesus was given. All human life is now with a spirit of immortality.

> John 3:15 that everyone who believes in him may have eternal life.

> And I saw the holy city, new Jerusalem, coming down out of heaven from God Rev 21:2

This is the city - the Kingdom is much more than a city. This is the *centre* of the Kingdom which fills the entire universe.

> The city does not need the sun or the moon to shine on it, for the glory of God gives it light, and the Lamb is its lamp. Rev 21:23

God and the Lamb, will 'dwell' in the city. This is obviously somewhat figurative as God does not 'dwell' anywhere physically speaking - and neither do humans, though as relationship oriented and being totally at one with God we can barely imagine what this will be like!

However,

> “I tell you I will not drink again of this fruit of the vine until that day when I drink it new with you in my Father’s kingdom.”” ‭‭Matthew‬ ‭26:29‬ ‭

This is the time *well before* new heavens etc. It is when God's Kingdom with Jesus at the helm of the new age of restoration of all things in a world being prepared for the second resurrection of all who ever lived.

This is a drink of celebration as Jesus welcomes his friends, saints and OT figures to enjoy a feast and rejoicing of all the hard work, the sacrifice that was done and the final result of righteous rule on the earth again.

Answer (score 0):

Where is the Father’s kingdom’s final location?
matthew prophecy heaven kingdom-of-god
Jesus says
“I tell you I will not drink again of this fruit of the vine until that day when I drink it new with you in my Father’s kingdom.”” ‭‭Matthew‬ ‭26:29‬ ‭
Where will this kingdom be situated geographically speaking? In the heavens or on earth? New or old?

I think you have two scenarios in your question.  The first scenario is when Jesus will drink the new wine again with his disciples.  I would assume this takes place on the new heavens and new earth where righteousness dwells.  Jerusalem will be a city of joy and will have finally come into her own.  Sometimes this day is also referred to as the day of God.

> Expecting and hastening the coming of the day of God, by reason of which the heavens will be dissolved, being set on fire, and the elements are melting, burning with heat. But according to His promise, we are awaiting new heavens and a new earth, in which righteousness dwells.  2 Peter 3:12-13<

This is also God the father's kingdom Where it says he is dwelling with men.

> Then I saw a new heaven and a new earth,a for the first heaven and earth had passed away, and the sea was no more. I saw the holy city, the new Jerusalem, coming down out of heaven from God, prepared as a bride adorned for her husband.
> And I heard a loud voice from the throne saying:
> “Behold, the dwelling place of God is with man,
> and He will dwell with them.
> They will be His people,
> and God Himself will be with them as their God.
> He will wipe away every tear from their eyes,’
> and there will be no more death
> or mourning or crying or pain,
> for the former things have passed away.” Revelation 21:3-4<

I think the Fathers  Finale kingdom will take place after the eon of the eons.  At the very end of the ages.

> Then  the end, when He shall hand over the kingdom to the God and Father, when He shall have annulled all dominion, and all authority and power. For it behooves Him to reign until He shall have put all the enemies under His feet. The last enemy to be abolished is death. For  “He has put in subjection all things under His feet.”But when it may be said that all things have been put in subjection, it is evident that the One having put in subjection all things to Him is excepted. Now when all things shall have been put in subjection to Him, then also the Son Himself will be put in subjection to the One having put in subjection all things to Him, so that God may be all in all.  1 Corinthians 15:24-28<

At this time Christ will hand over to God a totally reconciled and perfected creation.  God then become all in all… Perfection!

Have no idea where or what that will look like.  His love will be the rule in  everything, and everyone, and everywhere....
Love never fails… God is Love!

Answer (score 0):

The kingdom of God is not a political geographical location drawn by arbitrary lines of men.

> *"20 And when he was demanded of the Pharisees, when the kingdom of God should come, he answered them and said, The kingdom of God cometh not with observation:*

> *21 Neither shall they say, Lo here! or, lo there! for, **behold, the kingdom of God is within you.**"*  (Luke 17:20-21, KJV)

And, future tense verbs written almost 2,000 years ago are not still future to us. The Olivet discourse told the time that the establishment of the kingdom would be in full force when the temple in Jerusalem was destroyed.  That temple was still standing when Christ told His disciples that it would be destroyed, so the verb tenses used in that prophesy were still in their future.  As the temple was destroyed in AD 70 the prophesy is not still in our future.

> *"34 Verily I say unto you, **This generation** shall not pass, till all these things be fulfilled. 35 **Heaven and earth** shall pass away, but my words shall not pass away."* (Matt. 24:35-35, KJV)

"This generation" was their generation of the 1st century AD - not ours.  Heaven and earth was a metaphor which the Jews used when speaking of the temple.  So paraphrase vs. 35 and hear "The temple shall pass away...".  It was also used by God to speak of the old and the new covenants.

> *"I call **heaven and earth** to witness against you this day..."* (Deu. 4:26, KJV)

What did Moses say would be used to witness against, or judge the wicked?  "Heaven and earth" was the law handed down in Exodus, the old covenant, the Mosaic covenant.

> *"15 And ye shall leave your name for a curse unto my chosen: for the Lord God shall slay thee, **and call his servants by another name**:*

> *16 That he who blesseth himself in the earth shall bless himself in the God of truth; and he that sweareth in the earth shall swear by the God of truth; because the former troubles are forgotten, and because they are hid from mine eyes.*

> *17 For, behold, **I create new heavens and a new earth**: and the former shall not be remembered, nor come into mind."*  (Isa. 65: 15-17, KJV)

The new heavens and the new earth, as opposed to the old heavens and earth, the old covenant then were the new covenant under the gospel of Christ.

So, Jesus told them in His Olivet discourse when He was coming with His kingdom, and that would be when the temple in Jerusalem was going to be destroyed, completely torn down.

> *"20 And when ye shall see Jerusalem compassed with armies, then know that the desolation thereof is nigh.....*

> *31 So likewise ye, when ye see these things come to pass, know ye that the kingdom of God is nigh at hand. 32 Verily I say unto you, This generation shall not pass away, till all be fulfilled."*  (Luke 21: 20, 31-32, KJV)

Jesus told them the kingdom was near when they saw Jerusalem surrounded with armies.

> *"21 Jesus saith unto her, Woman, believe me, the hour cometh, when ye shall neither in this mountain, nor yet at Jerusalem, worship the Father.*

> *22 Ye worship ye know not what: we know what we worship: for salvation is of the Jews.*

> *23 But the hour cometh, **and now is**, when the true worshippers shall worship the Father **in spirit and in truth:** for the Father seeketh such to worship him."*  (John 4:21-23, KJV)

"And now is"... current and present tense while Jesus was standing with the woman at the well.  Worshiping in spirit and in truth does not require a geographical location.

As Revelation was John's Olivet discourse, written in much Hebraic symbolism and metaphor about the destruction of Jerusalem - "that great city" - then seeing "the new heaven and new earth coming down out of heaven" was an event that happened after the temple in Jerusalem was destroyed.

> *"And I saw a new heaven and a new earth: for the first heaven and the first earth were passed away; and there was no more sea.*

> *2 And I John saw the holy city, new Jerusalem, coming down from God out of heaven, prepared as a bride adorned for her husband.*

> *3 And I heard a great voice out of heaven saying, Behold, **the tabernacle of God is with men,** and he will dwell with them, and they shall be his people, and God himself shall be with them, and be their God."*  (Rev. 21:1-3, KJV)

The new heaven and earth covenant - the gospel of Christ.  The "first heaven and the first earth" being old covenant, the old Mosaic covenant were gone when the temple was destroyed in AD 70.  Thereafter the new Jerusalem, adorned as a bride was / is Christ's assembly, the body of Christ, the church of Christ.  All who are in His assembly are in His kingdom and have been ever since that temple was torn down.

"No more sea" means no more gentiles.  The sea was a metaphor for all the pagan nations that surrounded the "promised land" of Israel.  They were called "floods" in the OT which God used to judge Israel and destroy the wicked (Isa. 59:19; Jer. 46:8).  Paul told them there were no more Jew nor Greek (Gal. 3:28; Col. 3:11), that  all who are in Christ are counted for the seed of Abraham (Gal. 3:29), then all who are in Christ are the true Israel of God no matter where they live, or are located on this earth realm.

The kingdom of God does not have a political, geographical location.  It is made up of all of His saints in His body, who are tabernacling with Him, which recalls the last feast, THE feast of tabernacles / booths, also called the Feast of Nations.  It represented the gathering of all of the faithful of God from all of the nations of the earth, no matter when or where we are - whether present in our mortal bodies, or having all already crossed over to our immortal abode in heaven.

As all those in Christ are the Israel of God, and as the kingdom came without observation and is within us, and as all who are in Christ are of every nation on this earth, then the kingdom of God is wherever the faithful are gathered.

See my post The Gathering of The Elect at [ShreddingTheVeil](https://shreddingtheveil.org/2017/07/30/the-gathering-of-the-elect/) as well as the Signs of The Feasts Parts I-III [here](https://shreddingtheveil.org/2018/07/17/the-signs-of-the-feasts-part-i-christ-told-the-pharisees-the-time-of-his-return/), [here](https://shreddingtheveil.org/2018/07/21/the-signs-of-the-feasts-part-ii-christ-told-his-disciples-when-he-would-return/), and [here](https://shreddingtheveil.org/2018/08/02/the-signs-of-the-feasts-part-iii-the-thief-in-the-night/).

Answer (score -1):

Jerusalem The entire world really.

Revelation 21:

1  And I saw a new heaven and a new earth: for the first heaven and the first earth were passed away; and there was no more sea.

2 And I John saw the holy city, new Jerusalem, coming down from God out of heaven, prepared as a bride adorned for her husband.

3 And I heard a great voice out of heaven saying, Behold, the tabernacle of God is with men, and he will dwell with them, and they shall be his people, and God himself shall be with them, and be their God.

4 And God shall wipe away all tears from their eyes; and there shall be no more death, neither sorrow, nor crying, neither shall there be any more pain: for the former things are passed away.

5 And he that sat upon the throne said, Behold, I make all things new. And he said unto me, Write: for these words are true and faithful.

> Psalms 22:
>
> 26 The meek shall eat and be satisfied: they shall praise the LORD
> that seek him: your heart shall live for ever.
>
> 27 All the ends of the world shall remember and turn unto the LORD:
> and all the kindreds of the nations shall worship before thee.
>
> 28 For the kingdom is the LORD'S: and he is the governor among the
> nations.
>
> 29 All they that be fat upon earth shall eat and worship: all they
> that go down to the dust shall bow before him: and none can keep alive
> his own soul.
>
> 30 A seed shall serve him; it shall be accounted to the Lord for a
> generation.

Comment: When you say 'the entire world' are you referring to the entire new heavens and new earth ?

Comment: God owns everything. When the second advent happens and the Judgment Day is complete . The eternity God rules all.

Comment: So just to be clear the kingdom will be both in the new Heaven and the new earth?

Comment: 2 Peter 3. When the Bible says new, concerning the earth or heaven, it means age. The Eternity.

Answer (score -1):

The Father's kingdom refers to Heaven, and not to this earth.

> Not every one that saith unto me, Lord, Lord, shall enter into the
> kingdom of heaven; but he that doeth the will of **my Father which is in
> heaven.** (Matthew 7:21, KJV)
>
> And he said unto them, When ye pray, say, **Our Father which art in
> heaven,** Hallowed be thy name. Thy kingdom come. Thy will be done, as
> in heaven, so in earth. (Luke 11:2, KJV)

In the Lord's prayer, Jesus taught the disciples that the Father and His kingdom are in Heaven.  The disciples were to pray and ask that this kingdom might come to earth and that the Father's will be done on earth just as it is done in Heaven.

Jesus was also clear that this world was not his kingdom.

> Jesus answered, My kingdom is not of this world: if my kingdom were of
> this world, then would my servants fight, that I should not be
> delivered to the Jews: but now is my kingdom not from hence. (John
> 18:36, KJV)

Jesus also encouraged the disciples with a reminder of what was in store for them in our Father's kingdom.

> In my Father's house are many mansions: if it were not so, I would
> have told you. I go to prepare a place for you.  And if I go and
> prepare a place for you, I will come again, and receive you unto
> myself; that where I am, there ye may be also. (John 14:2-3, KJV)

Naturally, we are not there yet.  Jesus will come to take us there--away from this earth to the place of the Father.

As for an actual *location* for Heaven, the best I have found from the Bible on this appears in the book of Amos.

Look carefully at the parallelism between the following two verses.

> Him that maketh the Pleiades and **Orion,** and bringeth on the shadow
> of death in the morning, and darkeneth the day into night; that
> calleth for the waters of the sea, and poureth them out upon the face
> of the earth; the LORD is His name; (Amos 5:8, JPS)
>
> It is He that buildeth His upper chambers in **the heaven**, and hath
> founded His vault upon the earth; He that calleth for the waters of
> the sea, and poureth them out upon the face of the earth; The LORD is
> His name. (Amos 9:6, JPS)

It seems that God's heavenly kingdom is somewhere near or past Orion--but admittedly, this is an inference, open to interpretation, and not a point that is relevant to our salvation.

**Conclusion**

The Father's kingdom of which Jesus speaks cannot be on this earth, but it does have a physical location in which Jesus is preparing a home for the redeemed and to which he will take them upon his return to Earth.

Comment: The logic is weak as Jesus said the disciples too were, 'not of this world' That doesn't mean they are in 'heaven' - it means they are *heavenly in status* - being declared righteous etc. Just as Jesus was *heavenly in status*.